# iphone: draw line with custom brush in Quartz2d

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-graphics, ios4

I am writing a drawing application on iPhone. I did the drawing with color and width, with CGContextMoveToPoint and CGContextAddLineToPoint function in Core Graphics. I wonder that can I make a custom style of brush, texture, to change the display style of the line? Because I would like to make the line like pen drawing style. I have checked GLPaint sample code of Apple before but I would like to do that with Core Graphics.

Can you have any idea of my problem? I am very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about CGPattern drawing and use `CGContextSetStrokePattern`

Comment: I did like your suggestion before but not success. You can take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593566/iphone-rewrite-glpaint-using-core-graphics. Do I miss something?